# Why can't I change the Google Calendar on an event after it's been sync'd?

Tags: sync, calendar, samsung-galaxy-s

Galaxy-S (Vibrant), Android 2.1

If I create an event with the stock Calendar app, I can freely change which Google Calendar the event is associated with.  Once it sync's with Google Calendar, however, I can no longer change which Calendar the event is associated with.  I can do change any other aspect of the event, and even delete the event, but I can't move it to a different calendar.  I can change the calendar from the Google Calendar web page, though.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why, but I can tell you I can't do it on my Moto Droid either.  I believe it is a limitation of the Stock Calendar app and not specific to the Galaxy S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because of how the Google Calendar server API interacts with client applications.

An update request has to be sent to a *specific calendar* on the server.  If you could change which calendar the appointment is tied to, synchronization would have to send a "delete" from one calendar and an "add" to the other.

I've developed and maintained a number of systems which have synchronization and replication... and I suspect that a decision as made to favor simplicity and avoid the possible complexities of cross-calendar edits.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you are just restating the problem that the question is asking about instead of answering the question. Here's the way I read it... Q: why can't I change the cal? Your A: you can't.  BCooksey, am I missing something here? If I am I apologize but please clarify for my sake.

Comment: My wording could be better.  I was trying to distinguish that there is no edit option when looking at event details, but there IS an edit option in tap and hold from the event list.  On re-reading the question, it also appears that even with clarification, what I addressed isn't what was  asked!

Comment: I've re-written my response to address the question being asked. It took a little digging into the Calendar app source and the Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some third party calendars.  Business Calendar from Appgenix lets me.   I am not affiliated or compensated in any way.